# Google Bar Chart Customization

Tags: php, css, google-visualization

I got an issue with my Google bar chart. My chart look like this[image]

on the left are the questions, I scan this documentation [HERE](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) and try some but it I can't solve my problem, my concerns are:

1. Display the full question on left, (also if possible align it to left)
2. If we mouse over any color inside the bar chart it appears its detail, if possible can can we put its detail inside the color as label?
3. Edit font size and font face, & add thickness to bars.

my jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/hBu7p/1/

could anyone help me please. Any comments, links, suggestion is well appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. No. GViz truncates titles that are too long. Possibly a smaller font. It's also not possible to align left. By default, axis labels are aligned right.
2. Also, no. It's not possible (with bar char) to label values. There exists a column chart hack to display labels over columns in a column chart.
3. Yes, you can change the font size and face with the vAxis.textStyle parameters (or others, depending on what you want to accomplish). Check out all the published chart features [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options_). Changing the thickness of the bars can be accomplished by changing the area of the chart. The drawing area is determined with the golden ratio, so making a chart bigger will result in larger bars.

Comment: thanks for this, now I got wider idea now, but maybe there is a way look for existing libraries dealing with those issue or let google update its chart :) But thanks it is a big help.